# Bootstrap columns offsetting for no reason

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been coding out a form inside a bootstrap accordion collapse but there is an issue on md and lg screens with columns.

As expected on xs and sm, it looks like so:

[image: xs and sm screens]

Perfectly as expected, however when I go up to md and lg, this happens:

[image: md and lg screens]

I have tried inspecting the element and so forth but everything is as I would expect and should be working perfect, here you can see the parents width and then the widths of each child:

The parent:

[image: The parent row]

Each child:

[image: Each child]

As you can see, each child is indeed 50% of the parent, thus, there is no reason for it going onto a new line, nor for offsetting by 50%.

I have look at everything I can think of:

- Did I accidentally add an offset class? No.
- Is there a hidden col-md-6 that is doing the offsetting? No.
- Is the child larger than 50%? No.

So now I am lost and ask for ideas.

Here is a code snippet of the affected form:

```css
.payment-bottom-container {
  background: white;
  color: #C99C49;
}
.payment-bottom-container .section-intro-title {
  color: #C99C49;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.payment-bottom-container .section-intro-title::after {
  border-color: #C99C49;
  max-width: 40px;
  left: 125px;
}
.payment-bottom-container .final-step-text {
  color: #C99C49;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "montserrat-regular";
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.payment-bottom-container .panel-group .panel .panel-heading {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.payment-bottom-container .panel-group .panel .panel-heading h4 a {
  color: #190e8c;
  font-family: "Museo500";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.payment-bottom-container .panel-group .panel .panel-body form .col-xs-12 input,
.payment-bottom-container .panel-group .panel .panel-body form .col-xs-12 select {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #190e8c;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.payment-bottom-container .panel-group .panel .panel-body form .container {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.payment-bottom-container .panel-group .panel .panel-body form .delivery-title {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 24px;
}
.payment-bottom-container .panel-group .panel .panel-body form .col-xs-12 input.input-50 {
  width: 50%;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .payment-bottom-container .panel-group .panel .panel-body form .col-xs-12 input.input-50 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.payment-bottom-container .panel-group .panel .panel-body form .col-xs-12 input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #C99C49;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raeleway';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
}
.payment-bottom-container .panel-group .panel .panel-body form .col-xs-12 label {
  display: block;
  color: #063c58;
  font-family: 'Raeleway';
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.payment-bottom-container .panel-group .panel .panel-body form .col-xs-12 label span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="payment-bottom-container">
        <h1 class="section-intro-title">The final step</h1>
        <p class="final-step-text">Just let us know where you would like us to deliver your case to and it will be on its way!</p>
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Enter Delivery Address
        </a>
      </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="#" method="post">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h1 class="delivery-title">Where should we ship?</h1>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <label>First Name<span>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <label>Last Name<span>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <label>Address Line 1<span>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Address Line 1" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <label>Address Line 2</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Address Line 2">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <label>Phone Number<span>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <label>City/Town<span>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="City" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <label>Region/Council Area<span>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Region" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <label>Post Code<span>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <label>Select your country<span>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <select required>
                          <option value="UK">United Kingdom (GB)</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h1 class="delivery-title">Confirm Your Login Details</h1>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label>Email<span>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="The same as setup above" class="input-50" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label>Password<span>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="The same as setup above" class="input-50" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <input type="submit" value="Complete order">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope everything is clear enough, if not, comment below and I can provide any other information you may need.

Comment: There's no gap in chrome, or firefox actually, what browser you using?

Comment: No gap in Safari either, @AndrewBone

Comment: I'm using chrome Version 47.0.2526.80 m. @AndrewBone

Comment: Why would I apply a clearfix to it? I havent defined any floats as you can see in my CSS @JamesSnowy

Comment: @SkullDev and if you run your snippet and make it full screen it has the problem?

Comment: @AndrewBone Somehow not. Although, I put up a working example for you to see it in the site itself via the subdomain - here: http://goo.gl/hmA9J2

Comment: @SkullDev ADDRESS LINE 2 is 1px too short, which causes the problem, could give them all a fixed height I suppose? Actually the height difference is caused by the lack of a span so if you add a blank span on all the ones that lack an asterisk it will be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th answer was found by @andrewbone (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891666/andrew-bone) in his comment answer.

The issue was that my lack of asterisk above address line 2, it was 1px too short, therefore I set all of them to have a min-height of 72px and that upped the add line 2 from 71px to 72px tall fixing the issue!

Shout out to andrew for finding that was the issue!